# NLTK-based stemming and lemmatization

Tags: python, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

I am trying to preprocess a string using `lemmatizer` and then remove the punctuation and digits. I am using the code below to do this. I am not getting any error but the text is not preprocessed appropriately. Only the stop words are removed but the lemmatizing does not work and punctuation and digits also remain.

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import string
import nltk
tweets = "This is a beautiful day16~. I am; working on an exercise45.^^^45 text34."
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
tweets = lemmatizer.lemmatize(tweets)
data=[]
stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
words = nltk.word_tokenize(tweets)
words = [i for i in words if i not in stop_words]
data.append(' '.join(words))
corpus = " ".join(str(x) for x in data)
p = string.punctuation
d = string.digits
table = str.maketrans(p, len(p) * " ")
corpus.translate(table)
table = str.maketrans(d, len(d) * " ")
corpus.translate(table)
print(corpus)
```

The final output I get is:

```
This beautiful day16~ . I ; working exercise45.^^^45 text34 .
```

And expected output should look like:

```
This beautiful day I work exercise text
```

Comment: I'd use regex to get rid of the noise, before calling the lemmatizer.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. But should not the above code work as I am expecting. I had used the same code before and it worked, but not sure why its not working this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your current approach does not work, because you must pass *one word at a time* to the lemmatizer/stemmer, otherwise, those functions won't know to interpret your string as a sentence (they expect words).

```
import re

__stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))

def clean(tweet):
    cleaned_tweet = re.sub(r'([^\w\s]|\d)+', '', tweets.lower())
    return ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(i, 'v') 
                for i in cleaned_tweet.split() if i not in __stop_words])
```

Alternatively, you can use a `PorterStemmer`, which does the same thing as lemmatisation, but without context.

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer  
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
```

And, call the stemmer like this:

```
stemmer.stem(i)
```

Comment: Hey, Could you also advise me that how can I preprocess the text if my text is a dataframe column. I want to remove all punctuation, digits, and lemmatize text and remove stopwords from all rows of one column of dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for, but do this prior to calling the lemmatizer as the commenter noted.

```
>>>import re
>>>s = "This is a beautiful day16~. I am; working on an exercise45.^^^45text34."
>>>s = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z ]', '', s)
This is a beautiful day I am working on an exercise text
```

Answer (score 0):

To process a tweet properly you can use following code:

```
import re
import nltk
def process(text, lemmatizer=nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer()):
""" Normalizes case and handles punctuation
Inputs:
    text: str: raw text
    lemmatizer: an instance of a class implementing the lemmatize() method
                (the default argument is of type nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer)
Outputs:
    list(str): tokenized text
"""
bcd=[]
pattern = r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
text1= text.lower()
text1= re.sub(pattern,"", text1)
text1= text1.replace("'s "," ")
text1= text1.replace("'","")
text1= text1.replace("—", " ")
table= str.maketrans(string.punctuation,32*" ")
text1= text1.translate(table)
geek= nltk.word_tokenize(text1)



abc=nltk.pos_tag(geek)
output = []
for value in abc:
    value = list(value)
    if value[1][0] =="N":
        value[1] = 'n'
    elif value[1][0] =="V":
        value[1] = 'v'
    elif value[1][0] =="J":
        value[1] = 'a'
    elif value[1][0] =="R":
        value[1] = 'r'
    else:
        value[1]='n'
    output.append(value)
abc=output
for value in abc:
    bcd.append(lemmatizer.lemmatize(value[0],pos=value[1]))
return bcd
```

here I have use post_tag (only N,V,J,R and converted rest all into noun as well). This will return a tokenized and lemmatized list of words.