# Filtering out rows with non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a DataFrame from an existing DataFrame containing only the rows where values in a certain column(whose values are strings) do not contain a certain character.

i.e. If the character we don't want is a `'('`

Original dataframe:

```
   some_col my_column
0         1      some
1         2      word
2         3    hello(
```

New dataframe:

```
   some_col my_column
0         1      some
1         2      word
```

I have tried `df.loc['(' not in df['my_column']]`, but this does not work since `df['my_column']` is a Series object.

I have also tried: `df.loc[not df.my_column.str.contains('(')]`, which also does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for `str.isalpha`:

```
df[df.my_column.str.isalpha()]

   some_col my_column
0         1      some
1         2      word
```

A similar method is `str.isalnum`, if you want to retain letters and digits.

If you want to handle letters and whitespace characters, use

```
df[~df.my_column.str.contains(r'[^\w\s]')]

   some_col my_column
0         1      some
1         2      word
```

Lastly, if you are looking to remove punctuation as a whole, I've written a Q&A here which might be a useful read: [Fast punctuation removal with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444346/fast-punctuation-removal-with-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to filter out just that character:

### negation of `str.contains`

Escape the open paren.  Some characters can be interpreted as special regex characters.  You can escape them with a backslash.

```
df[~df.my_column.str.contains('\(')]

   some_col my_column
0         1      some
1         2      word
```

---

### `str.match` all non-open-paren

By the way, this is a bad idea!  Checking the whole string that it isn't a character with regex is gross.

```
df[df.my_column.str.match('^[^\(]*$')]

   some_col my_column
0         1      some
1         2      word
```

---

### Comprehension using `in`

```
df[['(' not in x for x in df.my_column]]

   some_col my_column
0         1      some
1         2      word
```

Comment: This caters to _just_ braces (if that's what OP wanted, then that's fine).

Comment: I'm highlighting how to escape characters that might be interpreted as regex.

Comment: Ah, because that's the reason their `contains` solution didn't work. Carry on then!