# How to use string.punctuation to remove punctuation in a text file

Tags: python, replace

Made a function to count 20 most common words in a book that I downloaded as a plain text format. The python textbook I am going off of said to use the `import string` and then the `replace` or the `translate` method to remove any punctuation, but when I print out the lines after the replace step, all the lines still have punctuation in it. I tried moving around the `line = line.strip()` and the `line = line.replace(string.punctuation,'')` step, but that did not work. I have never used replace so I may be using it wrong for all I know. Rest of my program works, just that step is frustrating me.

```
import string
def function():
    infile = open('gutbook.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
    count = dict()
    list2 = list()
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.replace(string.punctuation,'')
        line = line.lower().split()
        if line== []:
            continue
        for i in line:
            count[i] = count.get(i,0) + 1
    for key,value in count.items():
        newtuple = (value,key)
        list2.append(newtuple)
    list3 = sorted(list2,reverse = True)
    print(list3[:20])



function()
```

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50444346/7207392)

Comment: Your bug is trying to use `line.replace(string.punctuation,'')`, which tries to find the string of *all* punctuation in that order and remove it, not *each* individual character.

Comment: true, thanks @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import string

text = "Hello ! #$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ World"
print(re.sub("[" + re.escape(string.punctuation) + "]", "", text))
#or
print( re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]','',text) )
```

Comment: You've got a subtle bug here, that can be fixed by wrapping `string.punctuation` in [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), e.g. `re.sub("[" +re.escape(string.punctuation) + "]", "", text)`. Without escaping it, it won't treat `\ ` as punctuation (it interprets the `\ ` as escaping the `]` in `string.punctuation`, which prevents everything exploding, but also omits `\ ` from the set of characters to match).

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Thank you so much.