# How to increase the speed of using fuzzy matching in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to use fuzzy matching to check if dataframe contain keywords.

However, it is very slow to use `apply`.

Are there any faster methods?

Can we use `str` or `re`?

```
import regex

result = df['sentence'].apply(lambda x: regex.compile('(keyword){e<4}').findall(x)) #slow
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: At least you don't need to compile each time. `r = regex.compile(...); lambda x: r.findall(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why're you compiling inside the apply? That literally defeats its purpose. Also, the best way to speed up an `apply` call is to not use `apply`.

Without context to what you're actually trying to match, I present to you:

```
p = regex.compile('(keyword){e<4}')
result = [p.findall(x) for x in df['sentence']]
```

[My tests show that a list comprehension based regex match supersedes `str` methods in terms of performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50444347/4909087) Well, take that with a grain of salt, because it always depends on your data and what you're trying to match.

You may want to consider using `re.search` instead of findall if you just want a single match (for more performance).