# Delete Dynamic column values in Excel Sheet +Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Delete Dynamic values from rows in Excel sheet with Numpy

I tried using Numpy to delete

```
df['Requirement'].replace([',,',','], " ", inplace=True)

DS  Requirement
L1      ,,
L2      ,
L3      ,,,
L4      ,,,,
```

I have a above excel sheet and converting to DF, So using Numpy I am able to replace all the column values which are (Single Comma , double comma, Triple Comma and So on). Basically I want to make all the column values which having commas. Its all dynamic because it can be 1 comma or N number of comma's

Not getting any idea how to dynamically remove comma from column values.

Can anyone share some idea or I should go with manually check and make empty all desired column values?

Comment: `df['Requirement'] = df['Requirement'].replace([',,',','], " ", regex=True)`

Comment: Or better, just do `df.Requirement = df.Requirement.str.replace(',', '')`

Comment: Nailed it!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome, do consider upvoting the posts at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444346/fast-punctuation-removal-with-pandas because the same information is essentially there. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure..Upvote..I liked regex=True.