# Pandas remove all occurrence of white spaces

Tags: pandas, sas

In SAS, there is a compress function, which , when used without arguments on a string, will remove all white spaces, leading , trailing and in between.
Is there a equivalent function in pandas? So:

```
have: ABC XYZ
want:ABCXYZ
```

Comment: What data structure is `ABC XYZ`? A string, a `Series` of characters, one of it a blank? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `replace`

```
pd.Series(['ABC XYZ']).str.replace(' ','')
Out[695]: 
0    ABCXYZ
dtype: object
```

Comment: What about tabs, or other invisible characters? Will it compress all white space?

Comment: @Reeza https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444346/fast-punctuation-removal-with-pandas/50444347#50444347