# Create new column returning true/false if names in two columns match using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe where I am trying to match the columns string values of two columns to create a new column that returns true if the two column values match or false if they don't.
Want to use match and regex, remove all non-alphanumeric characters and use lowercase to match the names

pattern = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')

```
    Name A         Name B
0   yGZ,)          ygz.
1   (CGI)          C.G.I
2   Exto           exto.
3   Golden         UTF
```

I was thinking of trying something like this:

```
dataframe['Name A', 'Name B'].str.match(pattern, flags= re.IGNORECASE)

    Name A         Name B    Result
0   yGZ,)          ygz.       True
1   (CGI)          C.G.I      True
2   Exto           exto.      True
3   Golden         UTF        False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` to remove punctuation (also see another post of mine, [Fast punctuation removal with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444346/fast-punctuation-removal-with-pandas)), then

```
u = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[^\w]', '').str.lower())
df['Result'] = u['Name A'] == u['Name B']
df

   Name A Name B  Result
0   yGZ,)   ygz.    True
1   (CGI)  C.G.I    True
2    Exto  exto.    True
3  Golden    UTF   False
```

Comment: Im getting this error
AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index Number')
sorry I shouldve mentioned there are other columns which have numeric values

Comment: @TH14 Change the first line to: `u = df[['Name A', 'Name B']].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[^\w]', '').str.lower())` and it should work

Answer (score 3):

Can use `pd.DataFrame.replace` to clean your strings, and then compare using `eq`. Of course, if you wish to maintain a copy of your original `df`, just assign the returned data frame to a new variable ;}

```
df = df.replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", '', regex=True)
```

Then

```
df['Result'] = df['Name A'].str.lower().eq(df['Name B'].str.lower())
```

Outputs

```
    Name A  Name B  Result
0   yGZ     ygz     True
1   CGI     CGI     True
2   Exto    exto    True
3   Golden  UTF     False
```

Comment: for foreign characters the cleaned version of the column shows up as blank, is there any fix for that?

Comment: @TH14 you just slice the columns first to apply the replace in the data frame of interest... for example, `df[cols].replace(...)` where `cols=['Name A', 'Name B']` for instance.