# how to remove auto indexing in csv when converting to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm converting my csv into dataframe using pandas but when printing it it prints index automatically I tried to use

```
index=false
```

and

```
dataframe.drop(['Unnamed 0']
```

but non worked 
this is the code

```
data = pd.read_csv('testlast.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
print(data)
```

the output looks like

[image]

that is how the sentence look like in csv [image]

how to remove those auto generated numbers

Comment: What is reason for it? Because in pandas it is called index and cannot be removed. Or need remove if write to file like `df.to_csv(file, index=False)` ?

Comment: because I'm trying to find the frequency of the words and it will count the numbers for some reason as well

Comment: also use utf encoding to read the dataset `pd.read_csv('testlast.csv', encoding='utf8',index_col='false')` index_col=False can be used to force pandas to not use the first column as the index

Comment: OK, if use `print (df['sentences'].iat[0])` there is `0` values? If not, just ignore it. If yes, there is no separator tab in file.

Comment: but this one is just printing one sentence from the whole set not all of it

Comment: I added the csv picture as well but when printing the index appears which I dont want, I don't understand why pandas is adding it automatically @jezrael

Comment: pandas working this way, always generated some index values, here are defaul index values.

Comment: this time it says TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' @jezrael

Comment: that makes things easier thank you sir

Comment: @jezrael is there a way to save the created df into a txt or csv file with words and the frequency next  to it like an easy go around way ?

Comment: perfectly worked,  thank you, can you post that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Series` and `DataFrame` in pandas have always index, reasons are [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html):

> The axis labeling information in pandas objects serves many purposes:
>
> Identifies data (i.e. provides metadata) using known indicators, important for analysis, visualization, and interactive console display.
> Enables automatic and explicit data alignment.
> Allows intuitive getting and setting of subsets of the data set.

So for working with data you can ignore it (if not necessary for data processing):

```
df1 = (df['sentences'].str.split(expand=True)
                      .stack()
                      .value_counts()
                      .rename_axis('a')
                      .reset_index(name='b'))
```

Last for avoid write index to file add `index=False` parameter to [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df1.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: hey @Jezreal is there a way to remove the string punctuation inside your code ?

Comment: @programmingfreak - You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444346/fast-punctuation-removal-with-pandas)

Comment: I tried this  ```
 df2=set([x for i in data['sentences'].str.split().apply(lambda x: [''.join([y for y in i if y not in string.punctuation]) for i in x]).tolist() for x in i])```  it gives me the list of words correctly without punctuation but it doesnt print the frequency as yours

Comment: @programmingfreak - Maybe need `pd.Series(df2).value_counts()`

Comment: it says TypeError: 'set' type is unordered

Comment: @programmingfreak - hmm, then use `pd.Series(list(df2)).value_counts()`